# innerHTML no muestra mi variable

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Estoy comenzando a aprender html y js, tengo el siguiente problema:

Estoy intentando que la variable finalTxt se muestre en mi innerHTML. Cuando pongo otras variables o texto sí las muestra. El programa es para cifrar una palabra con el Cifrado César dejando que el usuario elija el offset.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Semillas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ropa+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
      Nombre de usuario: <input type="text" id="nText">

      Número de la suerte: <input type="number" id="offNumber" min="0" max="26">

    <input id="cipher" class="send-btn" type="button" value="Send"/>

<div id="showResult"></div>



</body>
<script src="cipher.js"> </script>
</html>
```

js:

```
var cipherFunction = document.getElementById('cipher');
var decipherFunction = document.getElementById('decipher');

cipherFunction.addEventListener("click", cipher);
if(decipherFunction){
decipherFunction.addEventListener("click", decipher);
}

function cipher (offNum, nTxt) {
  var nTxt = document.getElementById('nText').value;
  var offNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("offNumber").value);
  var i=0;
  var finalTxt = " ";

    for (i=0; i<=nTxt.length; i++){

      r=(nTxt.charCodeAt(i) -65 +offNum) %26 +65;
      var finalTxt= String.fromCharCode(r);
console.log(finalTxt);
document.getElementById("showResult").innerHTML = finalTxt;
}
}


function decipher (offNum, nTxt) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Paso 1**

Recomendación: Asigna el `div` en el cual deseas mostrar el resultado a una variable de este modo:

```
let showResult = document.getElementById('showResult')
```

**Paso 2**

Posterior, si revisas el resultado del `console.log` verás que obtienes un resultado como este:

```
"H"
"S"
"M"
"H"
""
```

Lo cual hace que cuando asignas el valor calculado por medio de `innerHTML` tome el último que es un espacio vacío y haga lucir como si no se viera nada.

Entonces puedes hacer lo siguiente:

al resultado le concatenas con `+` cada valor recuperado resultado de las iteraciones así de modo que en lugar de escribir en el `div` ese vacío tome cada una de las letras generadas las junte y lo muestre como el resultado final:

```
showResult.innerHTML += finalTxt;
```

**Paso 3**

Y de paso a tu `for` le haces la siguiente modificación:

Pasas de esto:

```
for (i=0; i<=nTxt.length; i++){
```

A esto:

```
for (i=0; i<nTxt.length; i++){
```

**Nota**

> Lo anterior para que el resultado no genere esto `""` lo cual fue una de las causas que hacía lucir como su tu `div` se quedara vacío

Lo anterior lo puedes comprobar si:

- Dejas tu `for` con la condición de `<`
- Ingresas el texto *perro*
- Ingresas el número *2*

Lo anterior te dará como resultado en consola:

```
"X"
"M"
"Z"
"Z"
"W"
```

Si evitas hacer uso de **`+=`** y solo asignas con **`=`**, entonces el único valor que verás en el `div` será:

> W

Que es la última letra generada

Answer (score 1):

Eso es porque el contenido estás reeemplazando con cada letra que obtienes con un espacio al final haciendo que no se muestre nada. Cambiando un poco tu código.

```js
var cipherFunction = document.getElementById('cipher');
var decipherFunction = document.getElementById('decipher');

cipherFunction.addEventListener("click", cipher);
if(decipherFunction){
  decipherFunction.addEventListener("click", decipher);
}

function cipher (offNum, nTxt) {
  var nTxt = document.getElementById('nText').value;
  var offNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("offNumber").value);
  var i=0;
  var finalTxt = " ";
  
  document.getElementById("showResult").innerHTML = "";

  for (i=0; i<nTxt.length; i++){
    r=(nTxt.charCodeAt(i) -65 +offNum) %26 +65;
    var finalTxt= String.fromCharCode(r);
    console.log(finalTxt);
    document.getElementById("showResult").innerHTML += finalTxt;
  }
}


function decipher (offNum, nTxt) {

}
```

```html
Nombre de usuario: <input type="text" id="nText">
Número de la suerte: <input type="number" id="offNumber" min="0" max="26">
<input id="cipher" class="send-btn" type="button" value="Send"/>

<div id="showResult"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aparte de lo que te han dicho los compañeros, observo algunas malas prácticas en tu código y me permito hacerte algunas recomendaciones.

- Crear una referencia global a los elementos fijos, luego en las diferentes funciones donde necesites alguna propiedad de esos elementos usas su referencia. Esto evitará estar llamando constantemente a `document.getElementById`, lo cual tiene su costo para al rendimiento.
- Evitar modificar elementos del DOM dentro de bucles. Esto haría que el DOM tenga que recargarse cada vez para asumir esa modificación. En esos casos es mejor recoger los resultados en una variable dentro del bucle y una vez sales del bucle modificas **una sola vez** el elemento, no `N` veces, donde `N` es el número de iteracciones del bucle. Esta es una de las malas prácticas más expandidas en la red. Imagina un bucle con 10,000 iteracciones, estarías modificando el DOM 10,000 veces.
- Con respecto a la seguridad, la documentación recomienda dar preferencia a `textContent` con respecto a `innerHTML` cuando el contenido que se está manejando es texto simple. El problema es `innerHTML` es menos seguro, y podría admitir en cierto casos tipos de ataque XSS.

He aplicado todo esto en el código de más abajo. He hecho algunas pruebas y comentarios, de modo que puedas comprender lo antes afirmado cuando revises las modificaciones.

```js
/*Referencias a los elementos fijos*/
const cipherFunction = document.getElementById('cipher');
const decipherFunction = document.getElementById('decipher');
const elTxt = document.getElementById('nText');
const elNumber = document.getElementById("offNumber");
const showResult = document.getElementById("showResult");

cipherFunction.addEventListener("click", cipher);
if (decipherFunction) {
  decipherFunction.addEventListener("click", decipher);
}

function cipher(offNum, nTxt) {
  /*Usamos las referencias ya creadas para obtener los value actuales*/
  var nTxt = elTxt.value;
  var offNum = parseInt(elNumber.value);
  var i = 0;
  var finalTxt = "";

  //showResult.innerHTML = ""; *Esto no tiene sentido*

  for (i = 0; i < nTxt.length; i++) {
    r = (nTxt.charCodeAt(i) - 65 + offNum) % 26 + 65;
    finalTxt += String.fromCharCode(r);
    //showResult.innerHTML += finalTxt; *MALA PRÁCTICA (ver test)*

    /*Test como evidencia de una mala práctica*/
    console.log(`${finalTxt} : Si modificas un elemento del DOM aquí, éste se actualizará por cada caracter afectando el rendimiento`);
  }
  /*Aquí el DOM se actualiza una sola vez, no N veces*/
  showResult.textContent += finalTxt;
}

function decipher() {
  /*Obtener valores in situ, coo cipher*/
}
```

```html
Nombre de usuario: <input type="text" id="nText"> Número de la suerte: <input type="number" id="offNumber" min="0" max="26">
<input id="cipher" class="send-btn" type="button" value="Send" />

<div id="showResult"></div>
```